# PHP namespaces, I just don't get it

Tags: php, namespaces

Say I have a folder with some files in them:

- Infrastructure/Core/Database.php
- Infrastructure/Core/Model.php
- Infrastructure/Core/View.php
- Infrastructure/Core/Controller.php

Inside each file I have declared the namespace like so:

**Database.php**

```
namespace Infrastructure\Core
{
    class Database
    {...}
}
```

**Model.php**

```
namespace Infrastructure\Core
{
    class Model
    {...}
}
```

etc...

Now I want to use all classes in that namespace. Imagine I have the following root file

**index.php**

```
use Infrastructure\Core

class Main
{
    $database = new Database();
    $controller = new Controller();
    //...etc..
}
```

This is almost like java and C# namespacing, but obviously in PHP it doesn't work... So the following doesn't work either:

**index.php**

```
use Infrastructure\Core

class Main
{
    $database = new Infrastructure\Core\Database();
    $controller = new Infrastructure\Core\Controller();
    //...etc..
}
```

Does not work either, so I finally think, okay I have to include the files too then... still doesn't work.. What am I doing wrong? I really do not get the millions of examples as it seems so different from any other namespacing I've used before.

Can someone provide an example specific to this one with the correct syntax so I can latch on to what it's all about with PHP. I assume it's a slightly different concept in php?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a description of an error

Comment: maybe `include "../Infrastructure/Core/Database.php"`

Comment: I do not get any errors, sorry mate. I'm using IIS, no idea how to turn errors on if there are any.

Comment: try using `error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: Ah so this should be working? @Sebastien

Comment: well, check out the enormous amounts of "how to get my error" questions.... but I've looked at my chrystal ball anyway and guessed some answer. but please, next time, find a error :)

Comment: Should'nt your index.php do something instead of implanting the Main class?? like Class1->printstuff("stuff") or something?? Just like a main function in C++ or C# ---> exemple: int main(){do stuff with class return 0;}

Comment: Not required because PHP does not need an entry point. Not compiled. but this is here for brevity, really my main class has a very entry like way of wrorking

Comment: What I meant is how do you know its not working?? maybe your code is running well but nothing is showing maybe you could at least echo something on success and something on error???

Comment: I see what you mean, I have left blocks out for brevity to be honest. lots happening just can't get it to run without error first (WSOD)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. your classes need to be loaded, so you either build yourself an autoloader based on classname // dir-name, or you manually include the correct files (so with `include` and/or `require`
2. 'use' is just for 'shortcuts', forget about that now
3. while your namespace declaration is correct, you have to call them from the 'root', so they start with a `\`

   ```
   $database = new \Infrastructure\Core\Database();
   ```

Comment: Right hangon, i'm giving this a try and for goodness sake that e report error isn't working haha. crappp.

Comment: just make sure your classes are actually loaded. If you need to, try to put them all in 1 file, then you are sure they are loaded. Then go from there.

Comment: That backslash is most likely my problem.. although now I realise 5.4 is not installed on WebMatrix, just sorting this out then I can tick this off as booyaka shann

Comment: What about static classes? Can they too be accessed: for example: \Infrastructure\Core\Stack::Push( "index.php" );

Comment: namespaces work from 5.3, so that's fine as well. about the static classes: just preprend your namespace to the classname. That works for calls (like static call), callbacks, strings (like for "is_a()"), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are a logical separation for your code the \ doesn't necesary means a folder path.

I haven't  programmed in PHP in some time but I think you are not using **include** or another mechanism to include the file contents.